# Signing messages in Truffle tests

Tags: web3js, truffle, signature, truffle-test

I use Truffle to develop locally and run tests with `truffle test` (letting it create a temporary local blockchain).

In one of my tests I need to sign a message and for that I need the test wallet's `privateKey`. Unfortunately Truffle's `contract()` provides only an array of `accounts` (an array of addresses). I googled and it seems that there is no way to get the private key for those addresses.

So I tried the following:

```
await web3.eth.accounts.wallet.create(1);
const wallet = web3.eth.accounts.wallet[0];

// ok
const signedMessage = await wallet.sign('message');

//  fails with "sender account not recognized"
const contract = await MyContract.new({ from: wallet.address });
```

The Issue: The message signer should also be the deployer of the contract but when I try to instantiate the contract as the newly created `wallet.address` I get the following error:

```
1) Contract: MyContract
       test case no. 1 :
     Error: Returned error: sender account not recognized
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/my_contract.js:67:43)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We observe that web3 exposes a few wallet functionalities that may  not be very clear at first:

1. `web3.eth.accounts` / `getAccounts()`
2. `web3.eth.accounts.wallet`

It seems `web3.eth.accounts.wallet.create` is a utility meant to create accounts on the fly without actually auto-binding them to your local node's account list (credits: [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51535303/5106700)). You could use `web3.eth.personal.newAccout()` but that still wouldn't give you access to the private key.

**Solution**

Using the two utilities, we can (1) create a new wallet (2) add it to the "personal" list.

```js
 /** Connect to ganache */
 const web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:7545')

 /** Create the new wallet */
 await web3.eth.accounts.wallet.create(1)
 const wallet = web3.eth.accounts.wallet[0]

 /** Bind the new wallet to the personal accounts */
 await web3.eth.personal.importRawKey(wallet.privateKey, '') // password is empty
 await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(wallet.address, '', 10000) // arbitrary duration

 /** Check wallet was added to accounts */
 const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
 console.log(accounts, wallet.address)
```

Small caveat here is that if you wanna pursue your contract creation, you also need to fund the new account with some ETH for gas.

Comment: @razgrafe hi, thanks a lot for the pointer! That indeed works. Do you have an idea on how I could then fund the new account? Should I transfer some ETH from an existing testing account?

Comment: I think so, maybe doing a transfer before importing and unlocking e.g. web3.eth.sendTransaction({to: wallet.address)} so you send funds from the previous default address

Comment: yep amazing! After asking I figured I should try that :) Thank you again for the help!